# Include APK and files in an android ROM compiled from source

Tags: android

I am compiling a ROM from source (say CM12.1)

I have obtained the source code and am ready to build.
However I wish to add an app (say ES file explorer) as a **user app** and another app(say Titanium) as a **system app**. Also I need to **copy a file** to one of the system folders.

How is this done?

> I dont have the source code of those apps and hence cant compile from
>   source.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to add the source code of the app the the **packages/apps** folder. Remove any precompiled files that exist.
2. Add the android.mk file. You can copy from it from the already available apps in the packages/apps folder and customize it for your app.
3. Add the app name to **core.mk** file in **build/target/product**
4. Build the ROM and it should have your file.